# How to close a hamburger-menu by clicking on an empty spot on the screen? (class: overlay-burger)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Which code I have to add to the JS, to close the hamburger-menu by click on an empty spot?

```
<div class="main-header">
    <div class="hamburger-menu">
        <a href="#" class="menu-btn">
            <span></span>
        </a>
        <nav class="links-menu">
            <a href="" class="nav-point">About</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-point">Services</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-point">Calculator</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-point">News</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-point">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="overlay-burger"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.menu-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-btn-active');
    $('.links-menu').toggleClass('links-menu-active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user click not on the button remove the active class:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.menu-btn')) { 
    $('.links-menu').removeClass('links-menu-active'); // remove active class from the nav
    $('.menu-btn').removeClass('menu-btn-active'); // remove active class from button
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works.
However I got a new issue. 
When I click out side of the window the hamburger menu is closed, but the hamburger icon remains with class menu-btn-active

Comment: Since you now know the removeClass method you could solve it by yourself. Check my Edit. Glad i could help - enjoy code! (:

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a fresh man in that, I know only HTML/CSS :(

Comment: You are doing great (:

Comment: Sure, I will mark it now.
Thank you so much bro :)
The final question is, I have to put your code into my current jQuery code or below it?

Comment: You can safely add it under the }); that close your "open menu" script.